# CSS variable in litelelement css function

Tags: css-variables, lit-element

I am using the css function in litelement to assign some values, like this

```
    static get styles() {
    return css`
        .formaFabrica {
            stroke: var(--svg-lente-stroke);
            stroke-width: var(--svg-forma-width);
        }
    `}
```

It works fine, but when i look at it in the devtools, i see this

[image: screenshot]

The CSS variable has been replaced by the value asigned to it.

This makes harder to modify the stylesheet, since we need to go to the source to know the variable name.

Surprisingly, the other style is not affected.

Is it possible to see somehow the original data in the dev tools ?

Comment: Could it be from the "color format" setting in chrome dev tools? Make sure it's set to "as authored"?

Answer (score 3):

interesting "issue" you have there... it seems the only way I can reproduce this is by adding the variable definition within the same css "definition".

As soon as I add the variable value to the `host` it works fine. Seems to be a browser bug to me :/

Putting it on the host could be a valid workaround.

Below is the code I used to reproduce - open it and inspect the different paths to see their result.

If you require an "external" css variable you can work around it by "remapping" it in the host like so

```
:host {
  --good-variable: var(--external-variable);
}
```

```html
<script>
  // can be used to disable constructable styleheets on chrome
  // delete Document.prototype.adoptedStyleSheets;
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  html {
    --svg-stroke-from-external: #ff0000;
  }
</style>

  
<script type="module">
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-element?module';

class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
        :host {
          --svg-stroke-width: 10px;
          --svg-stroke-from-host: #ff0000;
          --svg-stroke-from-host-mapped-from-external: var(--svg-stroke-from-external);
        }
        .formaFabrica {
            --svg-stroke-from-same-rule: #ff0000;
            stroke: var(--svg-stroke-from-same-rule);
            stroke-width: var(--svg-stroke-width);
        }
        .formaFabrica2 {
            stroke: var(--svg-stroke-from-host);
            stroke-width: var(--svg-stroke-width);
        }
        .formaFabrica3 {
            stroke: var(--svg-stroke-from-external);
            stroke-width: var(--svg-stroke-width);
        }       
        .formaFabrica4 {
            stroke: var(--svg-stroke-from-host-mapped-from-external);
            stroke-width: var(--svg-stroke-width);
        }        
        
        /* demo formatting */
        div { float: left; }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <h4>variable definition on same element</h4>
        <svg height="210" width="400">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" class="formaFabrica" />
        </svg>
        <p>Results in: </p>
        <pre>
          stroke: #ff0000;
        </pre>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>variable definition on host</h4>
        <svg height="210" width="400">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" class="formaFabrica2" />
        </svg>
        <p>Results in: </p>
        <pre>
          stroke: var(--svg-stroke-from-host);
        </pre>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>variable definition via "external" css</h4>
        <svg height="210" width="400">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" class="formaFabrica3" />
        </svg>
        <p>Results in: </p>
        <pre>
          stroke: #ff0000;
        </pre>
      </div>   
      <div>
        <h4>variable definition via "external" css</h4>
        <svg height="210" width="400">
          <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" class="formaFabrica4" />
        </svg>
        <p>Results in: </p>
        <pre>
          stroke: var(--svg-stroke-from-host-mapped-from-external);
        </pre>
      </div>         
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('simple-greeting', SimpleGreeting);
</script>

<simple-greeting></simple-greeting>
```

Comment: Than you for taking a look at my problem.  I am having the issue when the variable is defined in an external CSS sheet, but I don't know how to set a code snippet with an external stylesheet  Your solution is interesting, as it show a surprising difference in the way the browser handles this, but unluckily I can not use it in my setup.  Thanks any way !!

Comment: you probably can still use such a workaround by remapping your "external" variables on the host and then using the host variables in your css. => I added an example + explanation :)